# I am trying to read a .txt file into my program

Tags: c++, file

The file has different things it has to read for each line. I am creating a gradebook using pointer arrays but first I must read in this file that has been provided by my instructor. The first line(7) is the number of students in the class. The second line (5) is the number of assignments they have. The lines after that are the student identifiers and their respective assignment scores. Here is an example of the .txt file my program has to read:

```
7 
5
asd251  98.50   75  100 0   77
a3t46   83.50   100 100 62.5    77
6t23d   76.30   85  0   69.5    81.5
3kjl233lk   88.50   90  0   97  104.5
23kjk23lk1  98.25   0   100 93  95.5
12j1    76.00   75  50  87.5    104
142jjll 45.75   80  100 71  0
```

I was able to read the first 3 lines but i cannot read the rest of them. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream file;
    file.open("textfile.txt"); //name of file
    int numstud; //number of students
    int assignments = 0; //number of assignments
    string stud; //student identifier
    double a1, a2, a3, a4, a5; //each specific assignment

    while (file >> numstud >> assignments >> stud >> a1 >> a2 >> a3 >> a4 >>     a5)
    {
        cout << numstud << endl << assignments << endl << stud << " " << a1     << " " << a2 << " " << a3 << " " << a4 << " " << a5 << endl;
    }

    /*
    while (file >> assignments)
    {
        cout << assignments << endl;
    }

    while (file >> stud >> a1 >> a2 >> a3 >> a4 >> a5)
    {
        cout << stud << a1 << a1 << a3 << a4 << a5 << endl;
    }
    */
    /*
    while (file >> id >> studname >> age)
    {
        cout << id << studname << age << '\n';
    }

    */
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center. Could you also post your code directly, instead of an image?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's my first time posting on StackOverflow.